# Finding a way for script to detect a child in a playerContainer game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently making a 3D endless runner game with the choice to select different skins for the player. Everything's going smoothly until I come across a problem, in which I try to assign two collision game objects to each character prefab in the container that can detect the player's collision box when it collides with a powerup.

It only detects the first playerContainer's (Milo) 'Coin Detect' game object (eventhough it's been deactivated) and does not recognize the 'Coin Detect' collision game object in the Baddie playerContainer (which the player has chosen to play)

So my question is, how am I able to get the script to recognize the child that's active in the third playerContainer game object instead of it automatically detecting the first playerContainer game object's child?

From the Magnet powerup script I've made, the script detects the first playerContainer's 'Coin Detect' game object only. As shown in the attached picture below:

[image: My hierarchy of the playerContainer game object]

Here's my current script where the player is able to select their preferred characters.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnablePlayerSelector : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] players;
    public int currPlayerCount;

    void Start()
    {
        currPlayerCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedPlayer", 0);

        foreach (GameObject player in players)
            player.SetActive(false);

        players[currPlayerCount].SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

and here's the script where I deactivate the 'Coin Detect' collision game Object and activate it when the player collides with the powerup.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Magnet : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject coinDetect;

    void Start()
    {
        coinDetect = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CoinDetect");
        coinDetect.SetActive(false);
        Debug.Log("False");
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            StartCoroutine(coinActivate());
            Destroy(transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator coinActivate()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hi");

        coinDetect.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
        coinDetect.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can check how many children any object has. Theres a lot of code and a lot of words but there isn’t really a question in the words. .

Comment: @BugFinder thanks for noticing! apologies for not getting my point across, i've already edited the post to make the question clearer. 

in the case of checking how many children any object has, should I then just do a for loop with an **activeInHierarchy** to make it work?

Comment: Why. There’s already a property to get child count. Unless you need recursive count. However. Instead of disabling you could remove unwanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well your issue is rather that you are doing `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("CoinDetect")` which will return whatever is the first encountered `CoinDetect` in your scene in this moment. So unless `EnablePlayerSelector.Start` is executed **before** the `Magnet.Start` it will always be the first one since they are still all active by then.

You could probably already solve your issue by following the general thumb-rule:

- Do things where you do not depend on other components already in `Awake`
- Do things where you o depend on other components in `Start`

This way you already cover most of the use cases and are sure that components are self-initialized (`Awake`) before anything is accessing them in `Start`.

So simply change the `EnablePlayerSelector.Start` into `Awake` and you should be fine.

In very specific cases you might still have to adjust the [Script Execution Order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html) or use events.

---

Instead of doing this at all though I would rather in the moment of the collision request the current one from the `PlayerContainer` directly:

```
// put this on each player root object
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference these via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private GameObject coinDetector;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject playerrange;
    // ... and in general any information bout this Player that is relevant for other scripts

    // Readonly accessor property
    public GameObject CoinDetector => coinDetector;
}
```

and then rather have

```
public class EnablePlayerSelector : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Player[] players;
    [SerializeField] private int currPlayerCount;

    public Player CurrentPlayer => players[currPlayerCount];

    // In general do things where you don't depend on other scripts already in Awake
    // This way you could actually already solve your issue by keeping things where you do
    // depend on others in Start
    private void Awake()
    {
        currPlayerCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SelectedPlayer", 0);

        for(var i = 0; i < players.Length; i++)
        {
            players[i].gameObject.SetActive(i == currPlayerCount);
        }
    }
}
```

and then finally do e.g.

```
public class Magnet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float effectDuration = 5f;

    private IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        var playerSelector = other.GetComponentInParent<EnablePlayerSelector>();
        if(!playerSelector) yield break;
        
        Debug.Log("Hi");
        Destroy(transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        
        var coinDetect = playerSelector.CurrentPlayer.CoinDetector;

        coinDetect.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(effectDuration);
        coinDetect.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

or alternatively if the `other` in this case refers to the object with the `Player` component anyway you could also directly do

```
public class Magnet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float effectDuration = 5f;

    private IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(!other.TryGetComponent<Player>(out var player)) yield break;
        
        Debug.Log("Hi");
        Destroy(transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
        
        var coinDetect = player.CoinDetector;

        coinDetect.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(effectDuration);
        coinDetect.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this! I really do need to sharpen up when it comes to differentiating the use of Awake and Start when coding. I'll give your suggestions a try then, thanks again! @derHugo